# Is There A Way To Enlarge Status Bar Fonts And Icons In Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, themes, statusbar, visual-studio-2019

I was able to change the text size for code editor windows in Visual Studio 2019 by searching with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> for 'fonts`.  However, I would also like the navigable error/warning list icons and count labels in the status bar at lower left to be a bit larger:

[image: error/warning list icons and count labels in the status bar]

Here the Search bar let me down.  The only search results regarding 'Status bar` are to hide/show it altogether.

Are there any ways to customize the status bar in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: I too have this problem haven't found any way to fix this, with bigger and higher res monitors we have new problems... smh

Comment: The best I could figure out so far @Jason was to request this as a feature. See my answer below.

Comment: bummer...vs2017 added a lot new configuration that we cannot touch...smh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been suggested as a feature in the Visual Studio Developer Community:

> - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/934585/view.html

The best solution for the time being seems to be to upvote and comment on this feature suggestion if interested in seeing the setting implemented.

**Per Microsoft as of 2020-02-28:**

> *Feature suggestions are prioritized based on the value to our broader developer community and the product roadmap. We may not be able to pursue this one immediately, but we will continue to monitor it up to 90 days for community input.*